# jbd2/dm-0-8 consuming all I/O

Tags: centos, performance, io

What is jbd2/dm-0-8 and why It is consuming all my I/O usage and causing I/O wait?

Is there anyway to disable this?

Bonnie++ results: http://pastebin.com/iQCWP1qp

```
$ sudo hdparm -t /dev/sda1

/dev/sda1:
 Timing buffered disk reads: 108 MB in  3.02 seconds =  35.71 MB/sec
```

Comment: Replace the slow and possibly failing disks with faster disks.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned about slow disks I attached my bonnie++ results. Is this kind of a slow disk?

Comment: Sheesh, the three year old drive on my desktop is faster than that.

Comment: Oh, even the hdparm result (added to my question) is bad enough to cause this?

Comment: Some details on how I tracked down what `jbd2` was doing when it kept showing up with high % in `iotop` for me : https://serverfault.com/a/801223/181704

Answer (score 18, accepted):

jbd is the ["journaling block device"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journaling_block_device). dm-0-08 indicates a device mapped by device mapper.  It just indicates that you are doing IO and it is being flushed out to disk properly.  It is not by itself a source of IO.

Here is vague advice based on the vagueness of the question: If you need less iowait time, your machine needs to do less work, work more efficiently, or have more io resources to do work with.

Comment: Thanks, I tweaked settings as much as I could but still no change. I also added my bonnie++ results. I hope that might help if it's because slow disks.

Answer (score 1):

Was the filesystem recently created?  Is there any process named ext4lazyinit?

Then just wait as it inits (prepares, formats) the filesystem.